# Firebase 9 compilation errors using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase 9.5.0 in my react eCommerce project for importing the products from my Firestore database to my `ItemListContainer` component. I am aware that recent Firebase updates make Firebase threads prior to v9 useless since a lot has changed since and I can't figure out with the documentation how to import my Collections and Documents from Firestore database. I have created a `firebase.js` inside a `Firebase` folder in my project `src` directory.

My `firebase.js` using various online sources:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "(here is my api key)",
  authDomain: "reactcoder-17fc7.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "reactcoder-17fc7",
  storageBucket: "reactcoder-17fc7.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "588405796332",
  appId: "(here is my app id)",
  measurementId: "(i dont know if this is sensitive info)"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export function getFirebase() {
    return app
}

export function getFirestore() {
    return firebase.firestore(app)
}
```

Here is my `ItemListContainer` component attempting to get the Firestore Collection and Documents:

```
import ItemList from "./ItemList";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Product from "../../product.json";
import {getFirestore} from "../Firebase/firebase"

const ItemListContainer = () => {


    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    //i have found this useEffect online but pretty sure this firebase code doesnt work anymore.
    //this is a hook attempt at retrieving the firestore data
    //also cant figure out how to implement it in the context of my code/project
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const db = getFirestore();
        const itemCollection = db.collection("Products");
        itemCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            if(querySnapshot.size === 0) {
                console.log("no results")
            }
            setItems(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error searching item", error)
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <ItemList items={datos.Product} key={datos.id}></ItemList>
        </> 
    )
}

export default ItemListContainer
```

I feel like I'm getting nowhere, even if I get through all the compilation errors I don't think I'll be succesfully getting the Firestore database documents into my project. I'm also not being able to find threads or docs for my problem and feel like I am making a mess.

Any input is more than welcome. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my compilation error:

```
Failed to compile.

src\components\Firebase\firebase.js
  Line 26:12:  'firebase' is not defined  no-undef     

src\components\Items\ItemListContainer.js
  Line 13:9:   'setLoading' is not defined  no-undef   
  Line 20:13:  'setItems' is not defined    no-undef   
  Line 24:13:  'setLoading' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the compilation error message that you are getting?

Comment: Please post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: ItemList uses a bunch of state hooks that don't exist; functions must exist before they're used. Same with the reference to "firebase".

Comment: You may refer to a similar Stackoverflow case[1] and the documentation[2]. Let me know if that helps!
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959965/how-can-i-fix-failed-to-compile-src-index-js-firebase-is-not-defined-no-undef
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this one because some kind of varaiables missing.hope this will be working

```
import ItemList from "./ItemList";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Product from "../../product.json";
import {getFirestore} from "../Firebase/firebase"
import * as firebase from "firebase"

const ItemListContainer = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const db = getFirestore();
        const itemCollection = db.collection("Products");
        itemCollection.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            if(querySnapshot.size === 0) {
                console.log("no results")
            }
            setData(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error searching item", error)
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
      {data && data?.map((item)=>{
        return <ItemList items={item?.Product} key={item?.id} />
       })}  
        </> 
    )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).